# GIMP: test.scm gets "unbound variable" error when run

Tags: scheme, gimp

When I run this C:\Users\dev\.gimp-2.8\scripts\test.scm script:

```
(define (test pattern))
```

With this command in Windows PowerShell:

```
gimp-2.8 -i -b '(test "*.png")' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

I get this error:

```
batch command experienced an execution error:
Error: ( : 1) eval: unbound variable: *.png

(Type any character to close this window)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The message implies that PowerHell eats the double quotes for some reason.

Comment: Interesting! Running `gimp-2.8 -i -b '(test *.png)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'` instead has no effect, so I wonder how to get it escaped correctly.

Comment: `batch command executed successfully` when I surrounded `*.png` with grave accents, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a hint from @souser12345, the problem turns out to be with the command line. Surrounding the `*.png` with grave accents like this:

```
gimp-2.8 -i -b '(test `*.png`)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

will get this output:

```
batch command executed successfully
(Type any character to close this window)
```

Answer (score 1):

**MacOS**: Correct works with double quotes.

`gimp -i -b '(test "input.jpeg")' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'`